# Customizing Toolbar and other properties inside SettingsActivity

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to customize the style of my application inside the SettingsActivity.  I would like to change the **status bar** and **toolbar** colors, and if possible also the **window background**(from dark to light grey) and **text** colors(change white for black for example).I've read many websites and  I've tried different options in the style.xml but with no success. In SettingsTheme *colorPrimary* and *colorPrimaryDark* doesn override the default color of the parenttheme. Thanks in advance.

This is the main activity of my app

[image: app's main activity]

and this is the settings activity i have now

[image: settings activity]

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1A237E</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFEB3B</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_background_light_grey</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item>

    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenuListView" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:divider">#FF0000</item>

        <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">#3F51B5</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SettingsTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1A237E</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

toolbar in xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you use the Toolbar in settings? And may be you forgot to add "NoActionBar Theme" in Setting Activity?

(I know this may not be the answer but I couldn't comment because of the reputation.)

Answer (score 0):

Please replace above code in your Settings activity toolbar code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```